# DMN Nested Object Filering

Tags: drools, redhat, dmn

```
Literal Expression = PurchaseOrders.pledgedDocuments[valuation.value=62500]
```

Purchase Order Structure

PurchaseOrders:

```
[  
   {
      "productId": "PURCHASE_ORDER_FINANCING",
      "pledgedDocuments" : [{"valuation" : {"value" : "62500"} }]
   }
]
```

The literal Expression produces null result.

However if

```
PurchaseOrders.pledgedDocuments[valuation = null]
```

Return all results !

**What am I doing wrong ?**

[image]

Comment: You have a typo in that 'PurchaseOrders' -- the 62500 has a dangling `"`. Hopefully that's not in your actual data.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas its a typo -  corrected it ----- I was able to solve using `flatten` function - but dont know how it worked :(

Answer (score 1):

> I was able to solve using `flatten` function - but dont know how it worked :(

In your original question, it is not exactly clear to me what is your end-goal, so I will try to provide some references.

## value filtering

First, your `PurchaseOrders -> pledgedDocuments -> valuation -> value` appears to be a string, so in your original question trying to filter by

QUOTE:

```
... [valuation.value=62500]
```

will not help you.

You'll need to filter to something more ~like: `valuation.value="62500"`

## list projection

In your original question, you are projecting on the `PurchaseOrders` which is a list and accessing `pledgedDocuments` which again is a list !

So when you do:

QUOTE:

```
PurchaseOrders.pledgedDocuments (...)
```

You don't have a simple list; you have a list of lists, it is a list of all the lists of pledged documents.

## final solution

I believe what you wanted is:

```
flatten(PurchaseOrders.pledgedDocuments)[valuation.value="62500"]
```

And let's do the exercise on paper about what is actually happening.

First,

Let's focus on `PurchaseOrders.pledgedDocuments`.

You supply `PurchaseOrders` which is a LIST of POs,
and you project on `pledgedDocuments`.

What is that intermediate results?
Referencing your original question input value for POs, it is:

```
[  
   [{"valuation" : {"value" : "62500"} }]
]
```

notice how it is a list of lists?

With the first part of the expression, `PurchaseOrders.pledgedDocuments`, you have asked: for each PO, give me the list of pledged documents.

By hypothesis, if you supplied 3 POs, and each having 2 documents, you would have obtained with `PurchaseOrders.pledgedDocuments` a resulting list of again 3 elements, each element actually being a list of 2 elements.

Now,

With `flatten(PurchaseOrders.pledgedDocuments)` you achieve:

```
[{"valuation" : {"value" : "62500"} }]
```

So at this point you have a list containing all documents, **regardless** of which PO.

Now,

With `flatten(PurchaseOrders.pledgedDocuments)[valuation.value="62500"]` the complete expression, you still achieve:

```
[{"valuation" : {"value" : "62500"} }]
```

Because you have asked on the flattened list, to keep only those elements containing a `valuation.value` equal to the `"62500"` string.

In other words iff you have used this expression, what you achieved is:

> From any PO, return me the documents having the valuations' value
> equals to the string 62500, regardless of the PO the document belongs to.